# How to read and create new user by every 4th line

Tags: c#

So, I read a text file. It looks like this:

```
TEACHER - TEACHER/STUDENT
adamsmith - ID
Adam Smith - Name
B1u2d3a4 - Password
STUDENT
marywilson
Mary Wilson
s1Zeged
TEACHER
sz12gee3
George Johnson
George1234
STUDENT
sophieb
Sophie Black
SophieB12
```

And so on, there are all the users.

The *user* class:

```
class User
{
    private string myID;
    private string myName;
    private string myPW;
    private bool isTeacher;

    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return myID;
        }
        set
        {
            myID = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return myName;
        }
        set
        {
            myName = value;
        }
    }

    public string PW
    {
        get
        {
            return myPW;
        }
        set
        {
            PW = value;
        }
    }

    public bool teacher
    {
        get
        {
            return teacher;
        }
        set
        {
            isTeacher = value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return myName;
    }
}
```

The *Form1_Load* method:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    string line;

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("danet.txt"))
    {
        while ((line=sr.ReadLine())!=null)
        {
            User user = new User();
            user.ID=line;
            user.Name=sr.ReadLine();
            user.PW=sr.ReadLine();

            if(sr.ReadLine=="TEACHER")
            {
                teacher=true;
            }
            else
            {
                teacher=false;
            }

            users.Add(user);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to read the text and store the informations. By this method I get 4 times more user than I should. I was thinking of using `for` and a couple of things, but I didn't get to a solution.

Comment: Are you sure your data source is not malformed?
Your parsing method is not very forgiving; if one line were to get offset or if you have an extra (maybe empty) line in there, then everything would break. Since `StreamReader.ReadLine()` is advancing the reader, you should not get 4 times as many users. Again, look at your data source.

Comment: Instead of giving us a template give us your exact input, your exact output, and what you want the exact output to be

Comment: I've updated it. I'm not hiding my code, I just was lazy to translate it into English, since I also translated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### New answer

Your reader assumes the every fourth line is the user-id, it is not, the absolute first line is a STUDENT/TEACHER line. Either this is a typo, or you have to change your format.

Your PW property will cause a `StackOverflowException`,

```
        public string PW
        {
            get
            {
                return myPW;
            }
            set
            {
                PW = value; 
            }
        }
```

Change the setter to `myPW = value;`, or just convert them to [auto-properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).
Your `teacher` property has the same error, but on the getter.

You have also missed the `()` on one of your `ReadLine`'s, but let's just assume this is a typo.

Not using a text-file, but just a string so I'm using a `StringReader` instead, but it's the same concept.

```
        string stuff =
@"adamsmith
Adam Smith
B1u2d3a4
STUDENT
marywilson
Mary Wilson
s1Zeged
TEACHER
sz12gee3
George Johnson
George1234
STUDENT
sophieb
Sophie Black
SophieB12
STUDENT";

    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line;

        var users = new List<User>();

        using (var sr = new StringReader(stuff))
        {
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                User user = new User();
                user.ID = line;
                user.Name = sr.ReadLine();
                user.PW = sr.ReadLine();
                user.teacher = sr.ReadLine() == "TEACHER";

                users.Add(user);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

### Old answer

There is nothing inherently erroneous with you code. But since you have not provided an actual example of what your "danet.txt" looks like, one must assume the error lies within the data itself.

Your "parser" (if you want to call it that) is not forgiving, i.e. if there is an empty line in your source file or if you just mess up one line (say forget putting in a password or ID) then everything would get offset – but as far as your "parser" is concerned, nothing is wrong.

By default formats which depend on "line positions" or "line offset" are prone to break, *especially* if the file itself is created by hand versus being auto-generated.

Why not use a denoted format instead? Such as [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx), [JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) or even just [INI](https://github.com/martinusso/ini.net). C# can handle either of these, either built in or by external libraries (see the links).

There will never be any way for your "line-by-line" parser to *not break* if the user makes a faulty input, that is unless you have very strict formats for IDs, names, passwords and "student/teachers". and then validate them, using regular expressions (or similar). But that would defeat the purpose of a simple "line-by-line" format. And by then, you might as well go with a more "complex" format.

Comment: It's an exercise of an earlier competition, it says itself I can suppose the source and all the datas are correct.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your comment/updates. Either you miss-typed the text-file, or your parser handles the lines in the wrong order. Your code also has some very toxic errors in it. But I'm just going to assume that these are typos or possible old versions.

Comment: That's it, thanks. All these typos are becuase I translated the code into English, and I had to edit a lot of things (in my orginal code it runs properly.)

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((line=sr.ReadLine())!=null)
{
    User user = new User();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                user.ID = line;
                break;
            case 2:
                user.Name=sr.ReadLine();
                break;
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is prone to the same issues @user1660595 is having, just another way of writing it. Might be clearer, but ultimately, apart from a few typos in op:s code, it does the same thing.

Comment: @diemaus Oops. You're right. I misread. Once the user presents his data, I'll update the source accordingly (if the source needs changing of course).